# Using the correct local font name

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

As a small optimisation technique I want to serve the 'Avenir Next - Regular' font locally via css (so if a user has this font locally it will use it rather than download a woff2/woff/etc).

This font, for example, has been in IOS since version 6 so it's a quick win.

However I am not sure how to specify the local font name in the css stack? Do I need the word regular? Is there a program that would help?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Avenir';
  src: local("Avenir Next Regular"), /* THIS? */
       local("Avenir-Next-Regular"), /* THIS? */
       local("Avenir-Next"),         /* SOMETHING ELSE? */
       url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTW04Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTW04Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTW04Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Do I need to specify a font weight to get the 'regular' version? And then is there a way in devtools to see if it works? I presume not seeing a call to an external font file means success?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct font name as defined in the font file. If you are on Windows you can install Microsoft's [Font properties extension](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/TrueTypeProperty21.mspx). When installed, you just right click the font file and select *Properties*. There you will find extra tabs with the font's info. One of them will show the fonts name.

I guess it will be like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Avenir Next - Regular';
    src: local('Avenir Next'),
         url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTW04Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTW04Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/AvenirNextLTW04Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The font family reflects the base name of a font, while the variants are the children (font faces) and are defined by weight (e.g. `Regular`, `Bold`) and style (normal & italic).
When defining custom `@font-face`s, make sure to define a common font-family, so that font-weight and font-style gets applied properly and the font-face switches accordingly within the same font family.

There is no official naming convention for the various font faces themselves, but most fonts do follow this this pattern:
[Font Name] [Weight?] [Italic?]

The names for the common weights are usually `Thin`, `ExtraLight`, `Light`, `Regular`, `Medium`, `SemiBold`, `Bold`, `ExtraBold` and `Black`.
However, some fonts may introduce an extra space in the Extra-variants or substitute `Semi` with `Demi`. More about the possible names can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight).

Minor common exception: For the default 400-weight font, the name usually is `Font Name Regular`, while the weight is left out of the italic variant: `Font Name Italic`

Here is a table of possible font names for the imaginary font family `Cool Font`:

| Weight | Style | Likely name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | normal | Cool Font Thin |
| 200 | normal | Cool Font ExtraLight |
| 300 | normal | Cool Font Light |
| 400 | normal | Cool Font Regular |
| 500 | normal | Cool Font Medium |
| 600 | normal | Cool Font SemiBold |
| 700 | normal | Cool Font Bold |
| 800 | normal | Cool Font ExtraBold |
| 900 | normal | Cool Font Black |
|  |  |  |
| 100 | italic | Cool Font Thin Italic |
| 200 | italic | Cool Font ExtraLight Italic |
| 300 | italic | Cool Font Light Italic |
| 400 | italic | Cool Font Italic |
| 500 | italic | Cool Font Medium Italic |
| 600 | italic | Cool Font SemiBold Italic |
| 700 | italic | Cool Font Bold Italic |
| 800 | italic | Cool Font ExtraBold Italic |
| 900 | italic | Cool Font Black Italic |

Keep in mind, that your font family might diverge from this table, so it is always best to check the font itself.

**Example:**
Assuming the entire family of `Cool Font` consists of an (italic) Regular and Bold font face sharing the naming convention described above, the correct definition could be:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cool Font';
  src: local('Cool Font Regular'),
       url('Cool_Font_Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Cool_Font_Regular.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cool Font';
  src: local('Cool Font Bold'),
       url('Cool_Font_Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Cool_Font_Bold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cool Font';
  src: local('Cool Font Italic'),
       url('Cool_Font_Italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Cool_Font_Italic.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cool Font';
  src: local('Cool Font Bold Italic'),
       url('Cool_Font_Bold_Italic.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Cool_Font_Bold_Italic.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

If you don't know the correct variant name of a font, you can always define multiple local variants without any downsides:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cool Font';
  src: local('Cool Font SemiBold'),
       local('Cool Font Semi Bold'),
       local('Cool Font DemiBold'),
       local('Cool Font Demi Bold'),
       url('Cool_Font_SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('Cool_Font_SemiBold.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you don't want to let the user download a font and let it use the 'Avenir Next - Regular' font, you should put this font first in line in the font-declaration. Look into your own fonts for the exact name and set (only):

```
font-family: "Avenir Next - Regular", Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
```

But check if 'Avenir Next - Regular' is so widely local available (not likely, because it is an expensive font).

Comment: Avenir Next is a system font since IOS6 and recent OSX versions

Comment: IOS was in 2015 1/3 of all used operating systems

Comment: If you not want a user to load the "Avenir Next - Regular" font, but rather point to an alternative when the user has the font not local use the code in this answer.